# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm Building an App with Flutter. It running fine but when I trying to prepare for App-Store release using `flutter build iOS` OR `flutter build ipa` its showing the following error. I'm new to this iOS environment. (I do login with my developer account). Do I have to make any changes in Xcode Runner ?

```
    Sambits-MacBook-Air:sleepkart sambitdas$ flutter build ios
Building com.sleepkart.team for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: SDW79QN7H3
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            4.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    error: No profiles for 'com.sleepkart.team' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
    'com.sleepkart.team'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
    -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Encountered error while building for device.
Sambits-MacBook-Air:sleepkart sambitdas$
```

[image: XCODE Settings]

[image: xcode genaral]